# Is there .cs file equivalent for .razor file's @inject HttpClient Http

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, webassembly

in .razor file I use

```
@inject HttpClient Http
```

to get access to the HTTPClient.

Is there a way to do the same in a .cs file or do I have to pass it along as a parameter?

**update**

I thought I had it, but I don't.

Using statements

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
```

defined as class parameter

```cs
    [Inject]
    protected HttpClient Http {get;set;}
```

in my call Task

```cs
    await  Http.GetFromJsonAsync<SharedGLAccount[]>($"api/{ST_comp}/GLAccounts")
```

getting the following error

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'client')
```

Comment: in cs file you do `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();` and then call methods on `client` object.

Comment: Check out [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)

Comment: yes, thanks I think i found it, I will add answer once i have verified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use `IHttpClientFactory` for this. Checkout [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0) documentation which explains the benefits of using this and also copied below:

> - Provides a central location for naming and configuring logical    `HttpClient` instances. For example, a client named github could be registered and configured to access GitHub. A default client can be registered for general access.
> - Codifies the concept of outgoing middleware via delegating handlers in `HttpClient`. Provides extensions for Polly-based middleware to take advantage of delegating handlers in `HttpClient`.
> - Manages the pooling and lifetime of underlying `HttpClientMessageHandler` instances. Automatic management avoids common DNS (Domain Name System) problems that occur when manually managing `HttpClient` lifetimes.
> - Adds a configurable logging experience (via `ILogger`) for all requests sent through clients created by the factory.

An example of usage is:

In startup.cs file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient(); // <- add this
```

You can inject using this in a service or repository class:

```
public class BasicService : IBasicService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public BasicUsageModel(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) // <- inject here
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }
```

or this if its razor page code behind:

```
[Inject] public IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory { get; set; }
```

or this if its razor page:

```
@inject IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory
```

And use it like this:

```
var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient(); // <- create HTTP client
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Is it advisable to new up for each call? or better to reuse?